# Each row to return a count of elements within a range set by columns 1 & 2 in same row

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql

I can do this easily in excel (see picture for desired results).

[image]

Below is some sample code and my failed attempts using SUM().

Using the low & high values as the range, for each row count how many times the rows `KeyNms` appears in the `KeyNums` column within that range.

Note that CASE1 does return the correct count but it is using hardcoded values.

I looking for a way to do this dynamically. CASE2 returns TRUE for each row and therefore a count of all rows.

I’m thinking I might need a function or an array of some sort?

Any ideas how I can do this?

```
SELECT low, high, "KeyNms",
        sum(case when "KeyNms" between 35  and 57   then 1 end) over(partition by "KeyNms" between 35  and 57) as "Case1",
        sum(case when "KeyNms" between low and high then 1 end) over(partition by "KeyNms" between low and high) as "Case2"
FROM
    (SELECT l-11 as low, l+11 as high, l as "KeyNms"
        FROM generate_series(1,100,5) as l(n)
        group by l.n
     ) as t
group by "KeyNms", low, high
order by "KeyNms"
```

Using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> create table range (low int, hight int);
> create table keys (keynum int);
> insert into range values (3,12),(6,9),(24,40);
> insert into keys values (1),(4),(7),(10),(13),(16),(19),(22),(25),(28),(31),(34),(37),(40),(43);
> ```

You can use either an scalar subquery:

> ```
> select low, hight, (select count(*) 
>                     from   keys
>                     where  keynum between low and hight) count 
> from   range;
> ```
>
> ```
> low | hight | count
> --: | ----: | ----:
>   3 |    12 |     3
>   6 |     9 |     1
>  24 |    40 |     6
> ```

Or use a JOIN on keynum between low and hight:

> ```
> select low, hight, count(keys.*)
> from   keys
> join   range
> on     keynum between low and hight
> group by low, hight;
> ```
>
> ```
> low | hight | count
> --: | ----: | ----:
>   3 |    12 |     3
>   6 |     9 |     1
>  24 |    40 |     6
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a721cb540fec329ce2374ce84211f68e)*

Comment: I'm glad to help.